# How to privent population of same data in DataBase with Hibernate

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa, persistence, hibernate-mapping

I'm doing my own project and have something to store in mysql database.
After thinking  what should be a best solution DO NOT repeat same value's  in DataBase again I didn't find an answer.

So let's example,

Table `Cars` with rows `Cars_ID` and `Cars_VALUE`

```
-=JoinTable between Cars and Cars_CreationDate=-
```

Table `Cars_CreationDate` with rows `Cars_CreationDate_ID` and `Cars_CreationDate_VALUE`

```
-=JoinTable between Cars_CreationDate and Cars_Description=-
```

Table `Cars_Description` with rows `Cars_Description_ID` and `Cars_Description_VALUE`

In hibernate entities I would have relationships like this:

Between Entity `Cars_CreationDate` and `Cars` @ManyToMany, owner of relationships is `Cars_CreationDate`. Because many `Cars` can be made in one date and one date can have many cars.

Between Entity `Cars_Description` and `Cars` @ManyToOne, owner of relationships is `Cars` entity, entity `Cars_Description` belongs to `Cars`. Entity `Cars_Description` everytime extracts from database with `Cars`. `fetchType=EAGER`

Now let's see if we have in DataBase some `Cars` made already and I want to add new date to this cars I would say: 
`Cars cars = (Cars)session.get(Cars.class, int idindatabase);` // If we do this for a couple times more for different Cars we will have **THE SAME** `Cars_Description_VALUE` corresponds to different Cars so it would looks like this

> 2013-07-03 to CarOne
>
> 2013-07-03 to CarTwo
>
> 2013-07-03 to CarTree

and etc. So I don't need this dates repeat every time.

How do not let this problem to be??? Thank you

Comment: Its not clear what the problem is. You add a car to the Date's collection of cars.  There will only be one date in the database, but using a ManyToMany relationship with a join table means each relationship results in a row added to the join table.  If the car can only have a single creationdate (seems pretty likely), you can use a 1:m and have the car use a 1:1 to creationDate so that it has the foreign key in its table.  Or just put the date in the car entity directly and not bother with a separate table.

Comment: Sir, You almost answer my question.Yes my car has to have just 1 date. But if I will try to add the same date to different Car the date doesn't have to be added to database just because it the same one. Why I have to add it and copy it in my database? Right? And I think I mess with manytomany just because I thought it won't add same date every time for each Car, it will let developer decide how to accomplish it. I thought declare manytomany just for more stylish programming technique and never thought it depends on inserting. And what about JoinTable? Do I have to use them? Or FK more enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see much value in using a separate entity/table to store a single value to avoid having to write them out - either a car has a date or a car has a reference to a date.  I'd put the date in Car and be done with it.  But in theory, what you want is a foreign key in Car to reference your Date.  Each car will have a date ID that is used to find the date row/entity.  Your date objects then can have a 1:M relationship back, so they can have a collection of cars.
in CarEntity:

```
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="CREATIONDATE_ID"
  DateEntity creationDate;
```

In DateEntity:

```
  @OneToMany(mappedby="creationDate")
  Collection<CarEntity> cars;
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I want OnetoMany and ManytoOne biderectional relationships between Car and Date and Sir, what if I won'n be able to add all entities inside in Collection by ones?What if I will and one by one before add them to collection and save each single entity in collection. Will it add it to same date. As I think I have to get  Date class by id and after store Car in Date with particular ID. Right? You see the problem is I will add Car to particular Date and after I will also add Car with SAME NAME to different Date, now it will populate my same cars names in database.